# Error when copying Excel sheet with Python xlwings library

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Each month I run a report of scheduled appointments employees completed. The combined file is simple enough, each employee has their own sheet pulling from a sheet containing the full download of the month's data with INDEX/MATCH statements.

Each sheet contains a pivot table, as well as a separate section of filtered data.

I have a python script written that *should* work to separate each sheet into its own file, with filename equal to sheet name.

Here is my script below:

```
import xlwings as xw

EXCEL_FILE ='NPS_Report_Template.xlsx'


try:
    excel_app = xw.App(visible=False)

    wb = excel_app.books.open(EXCEL_FILE)

    for sheet in wb.sheets:
        sheet.api.Copy()
        wb_new = xw.books.active
        wb_new.save(f'{sheet.name}.xlsx')
        wb_new.close()
        print('success')
finally:
    excel_app.quit()
```

The script runs successfully for the first two sheets. These sheets *do not* contain filtered data *or* a pivot table, so this is my only real lead as to what's causing the issue. The script then hits an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dan\PycharmProjects\ExcelSeparator\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    sheet.api.Copy()
  File "C:\Users\Dan\PycharmProjects\ExcelSeparator\venv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 72, in __call__
    v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 47227, in Copy
    return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(551, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17)),Before
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "We couldn't copy this sheet.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

I will admit I'm a novice with the xlwings library, and to be honest I have no idea what's causing this. I feel like it should just work based on the script, but obviously I'm missing something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data that produces your problem. Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.